# Adding properties based on lambda expressions

Tags: c#, reflection, dynamic

I am using C# to create a view model that I later serialize into Json for use with KnockoutJs.

Now I need to add information on a property level if a certain user has access to view and/or edit the property.

Since Javascript has little to no reflection possibilities I want to do this with C# before serializing to Json.

My view model could look like this:

```
class ViewModel {
    public string Name { get; set; }        
}
```

I want to use a User Access Service that would take the user, which has some Roles, and the view model and go through the Roles and apply the access rights. Something like this:

```
class AccessService {
    public void Apply(IUser user, ViewModel viewModel) {
        if(user.Roles.Contains(Roles.Admin)) {
            viewModel.AllowRead(vm => vm.Name);
        }
    }
}
```

The `viewModel.AllowRead(..)` method would be an extension method that would take an `object` (or maybe an interface or type if necessary) and this is where the magic would happen.

I would like the result of this operation to be that the viewModel would get a new property with the name `CanRead` which in turn would have a boolean property with the name `Name`.

The resulting `viewModel` would look like this:

```
class ViewModel {
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public object CanRead { // Could non anonymous as well.
        return new {
            Name = true;
        };
    }
}
```

Can this be done with dynamics or do I have to use Reflection.Emit? I'm not asking for "show me the codez". I just want to know if my idea is mental or if it's possible.

Any ideas?

Comment: Is this `ViewModel` used in WPF?

Comment: No, it is used with KnockoutJs which is a MVVM thing for Javascript, hence the JSON.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it would be possible and you could use the [Lambdanator](https://github.com/jagregory/lambdanator) to *help* achieve this.

Example usage:

```
Lambda.Reflect<SomeClass>(x => x.AMethod());    
Lambda.Reflect<SomeClass>(x => x.AProperty);    
Lambda.Reflect(() => local);
```

Comment: While this would help me getting existing properties from a type based on a Lambda expression it doesn't help me in the Reflection.Emit, dynamic or whatever thing that would be needed to reach my goal. Still interesting though. Thanks!

Comment: Yes it's just the first step on the walk. I think what you're asking for is possible with Reflection & dynamics but I haven't tried.

Comment: I've solved it now. It's beautiful! I used a `dynamic` `ExpandoObject` on a ViewModelBase class that is exposed as a property. Then I stole some Expression magic from Lambdanator, basically just the `Expression<Func<T, object>>`, and created an extension method that adds a property to the dynamic object using `((IDictionary<String, Object>)theDynamicProperty)[memberAccess.Member.Name] = true;`.
It works really well! Thanks for the hint with the Lambdanator.